# How to get actual array from ember model?

Tags: ember.js

I have a model with a `hasMany` relationship:

```
var Bus = DS.Model.extend({
  model: DS.attr('string'),
  passengers: DS.hasMany('passenger', {async: true})
});
```

This seems to work, in that I am able to iterate through the passengers in my template.

Now I want to have an action in my controller that will do something with the passengers. It involves some business logic, and I'll need to iterate through the list of passengers.

My problem is that when I get the passengers from the model in the controller, it is not an array, it is some sort of object. How do I get an array from this object?

Here's what I have tried:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    start: function() {
      var bus = this.get('model');
      var passengers = model.get('passengers');
      passengers.then(function(passengerArray) {
        var stuff = passengerArray.get('content');
        console.log('The thing that I wish were an array of passengers',passengerArray);
        console.log('The type of that thing',typeof(passengerArray));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

It gives me the type `object`, and it is clearly something wrapped in emberness in a way that is inscrutable to me.

Comment: What are you getting back from the server? can you reproduce in emberjs.jsbin.com ?

Comment: I can't try that now, it's time for me to stop playing and get to work. I'm not hitting a server at all, though, I'm using fixtures currently.

Comment: it is probably returning a [RecordArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RecordArray.html), maybe its empty? it is indeed an [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html)

Comment: Why can’t you iterate over the result? `passengerArray.forEach(function(passenger) { console.log(passenger); })`

Comment: Hmm ... I guess I can. I was trying to use a `for` loop with the index, and that isn't working. Wanted to call a function that expects an array, guess I need to build the array myself.

Answer (score 3):

what's the output in the console of a `console.log(passengerArray)` if you use a decent browser you will get more than just object and actually beeing able to get informations on your object.

Some how when you use `model.get("passengers")` you get a PromiseArray of your "passengers" . using `then` is the correct way to get the datas, you will get an object which implements Ember.Array as the parameter of the function called in the then.

If you want a " raw js Array" you can get it by using `passengerArray.toArray()` function, if your goal is to iterate or get the lenght or what ever you can use the methods provided by emberArray => http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html

And as you can see in the documentation above `content` property is at least not public or may even not exist :) (you can also try a `passengerArray.get("[]")`) to retrieve the "content"

Answer (score 2):

Apart from if it is required/desirable. This would do:

```
var bus = this.get('model');
var passengersPromise = bus.get('passengers');

passengersPromise.then(function(passengers) {
  console.log('RecordArray', passengers);

  var passengerArrayWithRecords = passengers.toArray();
  console.log('array with records', passengerArrayWithRecords);

  var passengerArray = passengers.map(function(record) { 
    return record.toJSON();
  });
  console.log('plain array with javascript objects', passengerArray);
});
```

See it in action here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mapiyafaxa/2/edit?html,js,output

Reference:

- Ember.Map: http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/#toc_map
- DS.RecordArray: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RecordArray.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is a promise, since its an `async` relation. to access the actual array just do:

```
bus.get('passengers').then(function(passengers) {
  // passengers is the actual array
});
```

Comment: No, I get an object there too, I should have specified that, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it out using fixtures (so data is already in the store), I was able to get the array using

```
var bus = this.get('model');
var passengers = model.get('passengers').get('currentState');
```

I was then able to use `passengers[0].get('content')` (which is what I assume you want(?)). My guess is that for fetching the data from the server, you will want to use

```
var bus = this.get('model');
var passengers = model.get('passengers');
passengers.then(function(passengerArray) {
  var passengerContent = passengerArray.get('currentState')[0].get('content')
});
```